# Volume of unit sphere using a single integral

Tags: calculus, geometry

I was just doing this problem for fun, but I seem to be incorrect, and I cannot wrap my head around why. Consider the unit sphere centered at $(0, 0, 0)$. When trying to compute the volume, we can get the volume of the top half, $z \in (0, 1)$, then double it due to symmetry.

For each $z \in (0, 1)$, volume of a slice of the sphere is $\pi r^2 dz$ where $r$ is the radius at that slice. We compute $r = 1 - z$. For example, at $z = 1$, the radius $r = 0$, at $z = 0.5, r = 0.5$. By this, we can write an integral for the top half of the sphere.

$$V = 2\int_0^1(1 - z)^2\pi dz = \frac{2\pi}{3} \neq \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

EDIT: I actually think $r = 1 - z$ is incorrect. Would it be $r = \sqrt{(1 - z)^2}$?

Comment: ---> $r^2=1-z^2$

Comment: Thanks! I understand. I was being careless

Comment: Not $\sqrt{(1 - z)^2}$, but rather $\sqrt{1 - z^2}$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a half circle in $xy $ plane with radius $1$,we know that the volume $V$ is of a solid of integrable cross section area $A(x)$  from $x =a$ to $x = b$ is $V=\int_a ^b A(x) dx$

[image]

note the cross section area is a circle with radius =$AB =\sqrt{OB ^2 -OA^2} =\sqrt{1-x^2}$  and at canter $A$ so the cross section area $A(x)= \pi r^2= \pi (1-x^2)$

so the volume of the top half of the sphere is $V= \pi \int_0 ^1 (1-x^2) dx =  \frac{2 \pi }{3}$